# Error Inserting/Updating a row in a Database using SQL, Php and Ajax

Tags: php, sql, ajax

**UPDATE**

The SQL error I'm receiving is:

`Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (fb_id) = ('1018762834552473') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score='69139'' at line 1`

---

I’m creating a leaderboard table for a Javascript game and I’m currently trying to insert the player’s score into my database whenever a certain Javascript function runs.

I’m doing this with an Ajax Post using Php. I’ve put a console.log into the success area of the Ajax, and it’s appearing, which I think means that the php file is running correctly, but the score isn’t being updated in the database, so I think that maybe there’s a mistake in my SQL code.

This is the Ajax Post:

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'scripts/sendscore.php',
data: {'userid' : userid, 'score' : totalscore},
type: "POST",
success: function(response){    
         if (response.error) {
   console.log('Score input error - ' + response.error.message);
 }
 else {
 console.log("Score should be inputted correctly.");
}
}});
```

The leaderboard is for a Facebook game, so I’m sending two things in the Post, they are: the score, and the user’s id.

I want the php code to enter the score into the database where the user’s id that is sent matches the user’s id in the database, to simplify, I want it to insert/update the player’s score with the new score (a player shouldn’t have multiple scores in the database, they should only have one score). This is the SQL I’m using to try to achieve this:

```
<?php

$servername = "myserver";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "mydbname";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO scoretable (score) VALUES(:score) WHERE (fb_id) = (:userid) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score=:score");

$stmt->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
$userid = $_POST['userid'];
$stmt->bindParam(':score', $score);
$score = $_POST['score'];
$stmt->execute(); 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

The database table is made up of two columns, like this:

```
scoretable
========= 
fb_id
score
```

I’m getting the message “Score should be inputted correctly.” back in the console, so I think the problem might be with the line of SQL?

Any help with this would be really appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: I suggest adding a way to see the query on screen before it gets sent to the database.
This way you can check the query to make sure it is like you want it to be.

Comment: Check the score at the very end of the quesry, and also can you output the query what exactly it is trying to execute? 

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO scoretable (score) VALUES(:score) WHERE (fb_id) = (:userid) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score= ***(:score)***");

Comment: In Firefox you can see detailed information about network activity by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + Q` to inspect the response of requested file by AJAX

Comment: Hi @PixelMaker I've added an update to the start of my question. It appears the score is being sent to the database correctly, but the actual SQL has the wrong syntax.

Comment: Hi @Koneko-Chan and chay22 thanks for your comments, I've updated my question with the SQL error message.

Answer (score 1):

Note that ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE checks every unique fields in table, not just PRIMARY key. You want ON DUPLICATE KEY to match a UNIQUE key for score, then your INSERT will work fine without the WHERE clause. The bad news is that Mysql does not allow where clause on duplicate key update, so a quick trick would be to use if statement:
Try this statement:

```
INSERT INTO `scoretable` (`score`) VALUES(:score) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`fb_id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(fb_id),
`score`= IF(VALUES(:score) >= score, VALUES(:score), score);
```

Here, fb_id is an auto-increment field that I do not want modified by the UPDATE; hence the LAST_INSERT_ID trick.

Comment: Hi @mawia-hl thanks for your answer, I was wondering, what would be the benefit of using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE? I recently tried ``UPDATE scoretable SET score=(:score) WHERE fb_id=(:userid)`` This appears to be working correctly (it's replacing the player's score with the new score instead of creating a new row), would there be any problem with using this method as it seems very simple?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  updates a certain value if there is a record for that key already exists. It is an extension to INSERT statement. This tutorial [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/) has a very good example.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning values to variables $userid & $score after their binding.

Comment: You should assign variables before bind statement.

Comment: Hi @sujata-halwai Thanks for your reply. I tried changing the assigning of values to before the binding, but it's still not working. I have other php scripts which assign variables after the binding and they're working perfectly. I think the problem is in the Insert statement itself, as the error message shows the correct score and id appearing in the attempt to insert it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the data type and size of the **fb_id** (may be it is not able to hold the value with the data type you have in the database 1018762834552473)

Comment: Hi @pixel_maker , I just checked it, it's varchar(90), all my other php scripts are working perfectly handling the same data (fb_id) with rows of the same type and length.

Comment: try this
INSERT INTO scoretable (score, fb_id) VALUES(:score, :userid) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score=:score